# Unexpected characters in comment time

Tags: bug, markdown

Hopefully, this is the correct forum for bug reports. I have noticed twice today the addition of `-` (dashs) in the time of a comment. Bring the mouse over and the dash disappears.

[image]

The one pictured above occurs on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27004023/974781).

Browser: Safari 8.0

Comment: This has been happening in Chrome and Safari for a while (it's not an added dash, but rather the dash that's supposed to be between the comment and name/time is mis-positioned). I recall commenting on a dupe recently, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: No repro, mention your browser.

Comment: Repro on Safari 7.1 - and its quite a long time already. Was going to post this bug, but you were first :)

Comment: [Safari is not rendering things correctly.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243659/a-double-space-in-a-comment-removes-the-space-immediately-before-the-next-link) Who knows what Safari did to make the dash appear clear over there.

Comment: @animuson  Interestingly, the third comments above one in the page linked above, has NO `-`. It's missing. Not reproducible in Firefox. I will file bug report with [Apple Bug Reporter](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: I sometimes get this on mobile Chrome too.

Comment: There's nothing there, it's just something on my display.